# I have an error on the laravel flutterwave SDK: key required

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, flutterwave

I have integrated rave payment gateway in Laravel project. I have attached my `.env` file. Please have a look at it. But when it goes to transaction page after it showing this error `{"status":"error","message":"merchant public key required","data":null}`

[image: This is the env file]

Comment: where is mentioned .env file?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: @Emery never upload or share any document with API keys to any public platform. I suggest you generate new keys immediately as this is not a best practice in programming and compromises your account.

Comment: Yes, I have generated new keys

Answer (score 0):

The keys should be in string

```
RAVE_PUBLIC_KEY="FLWPUBK-xxxxxxx-X"
RAVE_SECRET_KEY="FLWSECK-xxxxxxx-X"
```